# Why isn't the frequency response of this band pass filter circuit the same as the band pass filter with an ideal op amp?

Tags: filter, band-pass

I'm trying to develop a band pass filter with center frequency 10 kHz:

[image]

[image]

The frequency response doesn't look good, but when i replace the circuit above with an ideal op-amp, I have the correct response:

[image]

[image]

Why doesn't the filter circuit with the real op-amp work as intended?

Comment: At first you should read the datasheet of the used real op amp very carefully and compare it with the requirements of your circuit.

Comment: @anilberg I have rejected your edit because it obscures the meaning of band pass filter (by abbreviation) and incorrectly renames "op-amp" as "OpAmp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Why isn't the frequency response of this band pass filter circuit the
> same as the band pass filter with an ideal op amp?*

You need to make the following changes: -

[image]

An ideal op-amp won't care what the power rails are or where the resistors above are connected to in terms of DC level.